Phonetically, does Ἐλωῒ Ἐλωῒ in Mark 15:34 resemble יְהִ֣י אֹ֑ור in Genesis 1:3?
My spoken dialect is swiftly moving toward having only one vowel (which I'll have you know isn't "woof!" [smile])
So I may be at some disadvantage with Ancient Hebrew. Certainly, once the vowel symbols are supplied, there are sounds being distinguished that my ear can't tell apart when I read back to myself.
This question is about the spoken-word phonetics of what Mark writes (not to the exclusion of what Matthew writes), not those of what Jesus did say. And it isn't about what the words mean, or why he says them, or what was his spoken language. I also hope this doesn't lend itself to mischief by being read back into disagreements to do with the sacred name, about which I'm generally innocent and wanting to be respectful of everyone.
It is whether the reduplication of "Ἐλωῒ Ἐλωῒ = eloi eloi" should be taken as creating any particular phonetic effect reminiscent of "יְהִ֣י אֹ֑ור = yehi ohr" in Genesis 1:3?
And if so, should there be heard in the last words Jesus speaks during the crucifixion and in Mark, a sense of the Word's original creative imperative, pouring out into a chaotic world, like in the beginning? (which words I pray involve no Christological insult and if they do I will gladly Edit) From a purely stylistic-compositional perspective, does this have Mark's gospel "bookending" with Genesis?
Despite it's being an obvious question, I couldn't find much about this in the online commentaries, which made me wonder if it is thoroughly excluded by what is written on the page, or by what was said by ancient commentators who were still close to these words' pronunciations in living language.
Bengel's Gnomen notes that "For not even שָׂרַי in Greek is Σαραῒ," So I wonder if when ῒ at the end of Ἐλωῒ is accentuated into a distinct vowel (from the ω), it might the more provide a "y" sound like the יְ in yehi ohr, onto the beginning of the next Ἐλωῒ
Wikipedia says (and I'm sorry I can't access the sources) "The word used in the Gospel of Mark for "my god", Ἐλωΐ, corresponds to the Aramaic form אלהי, elāhī. The one used in Matthew, Ἠλί, fits in better with the אלי of the original Hebrew Psalm, as has been pointed out in the literature; however, it may also be Aramaic because this form is attested abundantly in Aramaic as well." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_of_Jesus#Eli_Eli_lema_sabachthani
Ἐλωῒ Ἐλωῒ       (Mark 15:34)
אֱלהַי אֱלהַי   (Elahi Elahi < supplied, not from the text)
יְהִ֣י אֹ֑ור    (Yehi Ohr < Genesis 1:3)
This is only a similarity of consonants between Genesis 1:3 and what Mark might be transliterating. But can any more be said about the phonetics of the Greek and Ancient Hebrew that is in the text? And (as always) has anything been said that is wrong?
==
From searching past questions, I felt these ones and around 20 others were relevant, but didn't contain the answer to my question:-
Why did the bystanders at the cross misunderstand Jesus in Matthew 27:46-47?
what is the meaning of the Hebrew phrase " Yehi or" (translated as let there be light) in Gen. 1:3?
Why did Jesus say, "Eli, Eli, lama sabachthani?" that is to say, My God, my God, why hast thou forsaken me?
I don't have the benefit of Williams P.J. 2004. The linguistic background to Jesus' Dereliction Cry. The New Testament in its first century setting (ed. Williams P.J., Andre D. Clarke et al.) p. 7-8.
=====================
Relevant words and their locations (not comprehensive, there may be others and no account is taken of textual variants)
Eli Eli:    Ἠλὶ ἠλὶ       (Matthew 27:46, transliterating from Hebrew)
Eloi Eloi: Ἐλωῒ Ἐλωῒ      (Mark 15:34) - diacritic might be unique (Bengel's Gnomen)
Elahi: אֱלהַי אֱלהַי      (Aramaic/Hebrew < supplied/not in the text)
Elijah: Ἠλίαν          (Mark 15:35) - no breathing
Elijah: אֵלִיָּ֨הוּ          (1 Kings 17:1)
Elijah: Ἡλι            (1 Kings 17:1 - LXX) - breathing
Elohim:   אֱלֹהִ֑ים    (Genesis 1:1) - always ὁ θεός in LXX
Eli:      אֵלִ֣י          (Psalm 22:1)
Yehi Ohr:    יְהִ֣י אֹ֑ור   (Genesis 1:3) - let there be light
Yehi Ohr:    γενηθήτω φῶς  (Genesis 1:3 - LXX)
Hashem:     the one bringing into being (as a secondary register) (Genesis 2:4)
=====================

This is a lengthy question so I would recommend to you the recent Meta post: Avoiding the 'Great Wall of Textus'. To clarify, for the most part, are you asking if both sound similar?

In the list of relevant words you mention "Eli: אֵלִ֣י (Psalm 21:1)" - I think you meant to write Psalm 22?

Are you unconvinced that Jesus was quoting Psalm 22? If we accept that as the intended reference, then any other similarity would surely be coincidental.

I picked up the vulgate's numbering for some reason + will change to 22. Intertexts aren't 1:1 and a verbal echo to one verse and an assonance to another would be good style. What I'm asking about is the phonetics, and particularly if anyone knows what workings were done for אֱלהַי אֱלהַי =elahi elahi

First let us clarify that issue here is that Jesus seems to have recited the first words of Psalm 22 in Aramaic according to Mark, but in Hebrew according to Matthew. Mark records the Aramaic directly while Matthew records the Greek transliteration of the the Hebrew.
Beyond this, the list of relevant words in the OP all contain the the syllable "el" (god) until we get down to yehi ohr. This has no etymological connect to the other words that I can see. The word "Hashem" simply means "the name." It is a substitute word that Jews use for God's name, which is not normally pronounced. In English we do something similar when we translate this name (YHWH) and the LORD.
Conclusion: No, Ἐλωῒ Ἐλωῒ in Mark 15:34 does not resemble יְהִ֣י אֹ֑ור in Genesis 1:3.

good to have the input on etymology - this was about the phonetics: I tried to show from the (theorized) Aramaic transliteration, but it might be clearer just in English letters: elohielohilamasabacthani has the phonemes of yehi-ohr in the right order EloHIelOHilamasabachtani. I can get from the ωῒ to the הִ֣י and potentially the ω>אֱ but I'd want a phonologist's explanation. And there must have been one, for the "elahi elahi" theory to have stood. Also is there an onomatopoeic effect - of rushing breath - which the Greek is rendering in its own way.
